# Could you fetch me my bag vs could you fetch me the bag?

Tags: pronouns, determiners, collocations

> Could you fetch me my bag?
>
> Could you fetch me the bag?

Which one is correct?

Is it okay to say ' me my' together?

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct but mean different things.

In the first, the bag is specifically identified as belonging to the speaker. In the second, it is only a specific defined bag but doesn't state who owns it.

> Can you fetch my bag?

This is also correct and it doesn't specify fetching the bag for the speaker, but that might be implied in context.

> Is it okay to say ' me my' together?

yes, at least in some circumstances. They function differently and can be used together if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is perfectly grammatical to say "Could you fetch me my bag?"

**me** is the indirect object.  The indirect object is the person *on whose behalf* the fetching is done.

**my bag** is the direct object.  The direct object is that which is fetched.

> Could you please hand me<sup>ind obj</sup> my book?
>
> Could you please give him<sup>ind obj</sup> his hat?
>
> Could you please pass them<sup>ind obj</sup> their tickets?
>
> Could you please give us<sup>ind obj</sup> our privacy?
>
> Did they give you<sup>ind obj</sup> your assignment?
>
> The seer told her<sup>ind obj</sup> her fate.